# How can I select specific text out of markup to apply CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

In the example below, how can I apply CSS styling on the text `THIS` inside of the `p` tag, without applying the CSS to the `span` tag?

```html
<p>
    <span class='x' id='1'><a href='#'>y</a>.</span>
    THIS
</p>
```

Comment: select it how? can you please explain more?

Comment: very gentle question. how this question rise ?

Comment: `p { color: red; }` would do. Have other classes for each element to override it.

Comment: I want select text THIS... (inside P tag ) how can I select like... inside p and after span tag

Comment: You can't. Selectors select *elements*, not scraps of text. Wrap your THIS text in a `<span>` element with a class so that you can select it,

Comment: You should do it try to wrap "THIS" in a separate set of `span` tags, which is how you can easily use css-selectors on it.

Comment: Are you trying to select using jQuery? or are you tying to format using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can target that indirectly - by first targeting the entire p, and then targetting the span and the a inside it - effectively selecting everything inside the p that has a tag.

In the following I am targetting the "TEXT"  to make it red, whilst then over-riding that to target the other portions to give them different colours.s I then present a slightly longer version to demonstrate each portion as it is targetted.

```css
p {color: red}
p span { color: black}
p span a { color: blue}
```

```html
<p><span class='x' id='1'><a href='#'>y</a>.</span>THIS</p>


<p>
  <span class='x' id='1'>
    <a href='#'>This is a link</a>
  This is text within the span</span>
  This is another test
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the text in `<p></p>` except the contents of `<span></span>` you can use the `:not()` selector:

```
p :not(span)
```

Though as the `THIS` is not wrapped in an element, it cannot be styled by CSS independently.

If it's CSS you want, then I advise wrapping the `THIS` in another tag with a class. Otherwise, you can use css to format the `<p></p>` and revert the child elements styles, see [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset), [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit), and [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial). e.g.:

```css
p {color: red}
p span { color: initial }
p span a { color: initial }
```

```html
<p><span class='x' id='1'><a href='#'>y</a>.</span>THIS</p>
```